# How to select theme based on URL in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Suppose, I have a site named test.com and it has a selected theme of-course. Now I have other tenant site named alpha.test.com for which a theme is used also.

1. But I want to select the theme for the alpha.test.com from codes where orchard used to  select theme. How it is? Please help.
2. My another question is how to select different theme for different controller or actions in Orchard CMS.

Comment: If we want to select multiple/another theme based on URL then

Q1: Specify the currentThemeName variable with desired installed theme Name in GetTheme method of SiteThemeSelector class located in Orchard.Themes/Services. If you want to apply different theme based on URL then set currentThemeName inside logic and URL may retrieved from context.HttpContext.Request.

Q2: Specify the currentThemeName variable with desired installed theme Name in GetTheme method of SiteThemeSelector class located in Orchard.Themes/Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement your own IThemeSelector and use a higher priority than the default one. Do not alter the existing one like has been suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think these links may help you:

https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/359115

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dynamically-switching-the-theme-in-orchard

Answer (score -1):

There are no tables containing installed themes in Orchard but Themes_ThemeSiteSettingsPartRecord table is used to store the record for current theme only. If we want to select multiple/another theme based on URL then

Ans1 & Ans2: Specify the currentThemeName variable with desired installed theme Name in GetTheme method of SiteThemeSelector class located in Orchard.Themes/Services. If you want to apply different theme based on URL then set currentThemeName inside logic and URL may  retrieved from context.HttpContext.Request.

Comment: There is no need to alter the existing theme selector, and it's actually bad practice. The right way of doing this is to create another implementation of IThemeSelector.